# Jackson XML deserialization, Polymorphic mapping

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have the following XML that I would like to deserialize (shortened sample):

```
<annots>
            <highlight subject="Highlight" page="0">               
                <contents>askdhaskjdhaskjhsakjhdakjshd</contents>
            </highlight>
            <text subject="Comment" page="0" title="Guest" color="#FFFF00">
                <contents>Memo</contents>   
            </text>

</annots>
```

The code I came up with so far:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "subject")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Highlight", value = Highlight.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "Comment", value = Text.class)
})

public abstract class Annotation {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "subject")
    public String subject;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "page")
    public String page;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "rect")
    public String rect;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "flags")
    public String flags;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "name")
    public String name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "title")
    public String title;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "color")
    public String color;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true,localName = "opacity")
    public String opacity;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "contents")
    public String contents;

}
```

But there are several problems with this approach:

1. I do not want to use "subject" for the @JsonTypeInfo. Instead i would like to use the tag name (highlight, text, ...). How can I get this from the XML?
2. The @JacksonXmlPropert(localName = "subject") is always null since i use it for the type info. Why?, or how to get around it?
3. Or is the approach already wrong?

And finally the surrounding class I use:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "annots")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "annots")

public List<Annotation> annots;
```

Comment: Did you get solution for point 1 ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to parse this xml with correct `Annotation` sub types of `Highlight` and `Text` and the subject visible. I had to specify that this property should be visible:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "subject",
        visible = true)
```

Also, I am using jackson 2.8.8 and woodstox 5.0.3 for xml parsing.

The above takes care of point 2. Regarding point 1, I don't think this can be done with `@JsonTypeInfo` if at all, as the whole idea of it is to explicitly add type info at the resulting xml document. You may be able to work out something with [JsonTypeResolver](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonTypeResolver.html).